# Chromium “No Internet Connection”

Tags: xubuntu, internet, chromium

I am running Xubuntu 16.04 and I have Chromium installed, when I try to search by voice using https://www.google.com I get to another view where I can see "No Internet connection" and I do have Internet connection. If I use Google Chrome it works fine, but not with Chromium...

What I tried so far is...

- Already delete my cookies and history and everything and even installed it again.
- I have also permission for microphone.
- Chromium is Up-to-date
- Xubuntu is Up-to-date

Comment: Chromium must not be up-to-date. Google removed voice searching awhile ago.

Comment: have you already tried sudo apt install --reinstall chromium-browser

Comment: see if something like this helps you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YH2-cZMasiM

Comment: @AaronFranke i need it up-to-date :( ... and makes sense because it was working with an older chromium version....

Comment: @hellomoto yes i tried that and the video is not the solution, but thanks is more like the version of chromium browser as Aaron Franke said